# Better way to design layout for similar content in android

Tags: android, android-layout

I have designed the red highlighted layout like the picture:

[image]

What I have used is **LinearLayout** with orientation. Here an ImageView and Two Textviews are repeated in four times. But as far my knowledge I designed it using LinearLayout. So I have to write every time the same design code for four times.

Is there any better way to design it so that I have to write it one time instead of four times.

```
My code for the highlighted portion is [here](https://pastebin.com/C9ZHDaZV).
```

Comment: try using only 4 textviews with drawableLeft for your imageview and spannable string to customize your textview as per your needs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create one layout called for example `weather_layout.xml` and place your `ImageView` and Two `Textviews` inside, then just use `include` four times in your final `LinearLayout` like this:

```
<LinearLayout
    ...     >

     <include
          id="+@/top_left"
          layout="@layout/weather_layout"
          ...                          />

<LinearLayout/>
```

And then you can access like this:

```
LinearLayout topLeft = (LinearLayout) mainView.findViewbyId(R.id.top_left) 
ImageView v = (ImageView) topLeft.findViewbyId(R.id.imageView)
```

Comment: how can i call **findviewbyid()** in my activity class? won't there any conflict? @Jozef

Comment: just give every include different id and theres no problem. and you use `findviewbyid` just like its normal layout

Comment: like if i want to call top_left imageview what will the solution?

Comment: I have a question, doing this we are still using LinearLayout and the view hierarchy or complexity stills remains. I have read somewhere nested LinearLayout is costly. Any solution for it?

Comment: You can try to replace it with singe `RelativeLayout` or `ConstraintLayout`

Answer (score 0):

Use [Grid Layout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/GridLayout.html). That way you won't need to handle the spacing and partitioning yourself. One line of of code will suffice.